# Migrating from Spacy 2.3.1 to 3.0.1

Tags: spacy

This code works as expected when using Spacy 2.3.1, but throws an exception on the third line when using Spacy 3.0.1 (we also updated scispacy from .0.2.5 to 0.4.0:

```
entity_linker = UmlsEntityLinker(resolve_abbreviations=True)
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_sm')
nlp.add_pipe(entity_linker)
```

The exception is:

> ValueError at /scispacy/label_text/ [E966] `nlp.add_pipe` now takes
> the string name of the registered component factory, not a callable
> component. Expected string, but got <scispacy.linking.EntityLinker
> object at 0x000001B5297A7610> (name: 'None').
>
> - If you created your component with `nlp.create_pipe('name')`: remove nlp.create_pipe and call `nlp.add_pipe('name')` instead.
> - If you passed in a component like `TextCategorizer()`: call `nlp.add_pipe` with the string name instead, e.g.
>   `nlp.add_pipe('textcat')`.
> - If you're using a custom component: Add the decorator `@Language.component` (for function components) or `@Language.factory`
>   (for class components / factories) to your custom component and assign
>   it a name, e.g. `@Language.component('your_name')`. You can then run
>   `nlp.add_pipe('your_name')` to add it to the pipeline.

I'm not using custom components.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UmlsEntityLinker` is indeed a custom component from `scispacy`.

It looks like the v3 equivalent is:

```py
nlp.add_pipe("scispacy_linker", config={"resolve_abbreviations": True, "linker_name": "umls"})
```

See: https://github.com/allenai/scispacy#example-usage-1

Comment: Follow up question:  I'd like to use my own versions of candidate_genartion.py and linking_utils.py to avoid the time hit downloading the UMLS linker files and accessing them locally instead.  How would I do that with the new API?  I have it working with the older version.